# Resharper or VS2015 incorrectly wants assemblies to be referenced

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper, xaf

I aren't sure if it is Resharper or VS2015 that is underlining my code as shown in this screenshot.

[image: http://screencast.com/t/uNqP1AJxj]

The help suggests that a Dev Express assembly should be referenced.
However there is no need for the assembly  ( it is used inside the module that contains the DBContext )  and the code builds just fine.

Why is it incorrectly underlining the code ?

Comment: I do not know the underlying problem but I do know that all the developers on my team have this problem. We think it's Resharper.

Comment: Thanks Matt, in my case it is looking for devexpress.expressapp.v15.1.dll. How about you?

Comment: It's a lot of different libraries for us. It's several different solutions. Most of the time it is looking for the EF libraries but sometimes it is looking for our libraries.

Comment: Which version of ReSharper are you using? Have you tried clearing the ReSharper caches?

Comment: Ultimate 10.0.1  I cleared the cache and restarted Visual Studio but the problem is still there.

Comment: Do you have any Visual Studio or ReSharper extensions? Could be one of those that is causing this.

Comment: I am using Add New File 2.3.49 by Mads Kristensen, Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio,  lots of Dev Express, Web Essentials, Typescript for Microsoft Visual Studio, Visual Studio Installer , Open Command Line

Comment: I should mention that the issue is occurring in my Test project not my main project.

Comment: https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206546999-How-can-I-temporary-disable-turn-off-ReSharper- It is so easy to pause ReSharper, so why cannot you do that first?

Comment: I can't remember if that was easy to do at the time. I certainly would do it now.

Answer (score 1):

Click: **reshaper -> General -> caches -> clear caches**

Then restart Visual Studio. Any errors will be gone. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks, I can no-longer repeat the problem.  Since I upgraded VS and Resharper since then.